# How to join insert data from two different tables into the same row

Tags: mysql, sql

I am having an issue inserting data into the database. The SQL works fine but, it creates two different rows. How can I combine this Statement so it can run as one SQL statement?

```
INSERT INTO Transactions(CustomerId)
SELECT
    CustomerId
FROM
    Customers
WHERE
    CustomerId = '1033';
INSERT INTO Transactions(AccountBalance)
SELECT
    PlanRate
FROM
    Plans
WHERE
    PlanId = '11';
```

Comment: What's the point of `SELECT CustomerId from Customers where CustomerId = '1033'`? It will always return 1033...

Comment: this is some test code...I want to use this sql statement in php

Comment: Too slow to answer before it was closed: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=203bbcfbce5d2eb392225cd7de2bfac8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be like:

```
INSERT INTO Transactions(CustomerId, AccountBalance)
SELECT
    Customers.CustomerId,
    Plans.PlanRate
FROM
    Customers
JOIN Plans ON
    [JOIN CONDITION HERE]
WHERE
    [WHERE CONDITION HERE];
```

The point is you need to SELECT both columns in one query.